# QGIS add '.tif' raster layer using pyQGIS,bug QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7

i want to try to add raster layers(.tif) in QGIS using pyqgis first in python console first and after in the new QGIS plugin but i am very confused with that and specific to add tif rasters layers.
i use QGIS 2.6.1 (and i test all in QGIS 2.18.3 but i need 2.6.1 version) and python 2.7.13 in windows 10 or 7.

first i try this code from this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144058/how-to-load-a-raster-layer-using-pyqgis):

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
def StringToRaster(raster):
    fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
    path = fileInfo.filePath()
    baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
    layer = QgsRasterLayer(path, baseName)
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
    if layer.isValid() is True:
        print "Layer was loaded successfully!"
    else:
        print "Unable to read basename and file path - Your string is probably invalid"
raster = '/path/to/raster/file.tif'
StringToRaster(raster)
```

that not working for me with all rasters ".tif,.jpg,.png"

error :

```
Unable to read basename and file path - Your string is probably invalid
```

if i try this from official QGIS tutorial [post](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html):

```
fileName = "/path/to/raster/file.tif"
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)
if not rlayer.isValid():
  print "Layer failed to load!"
```

that working only with ".jpg" and ".png" but not for ".tif" rasters layers

error :

```
"Layer failed to load!"
```

and finaly i test this :

```
iface.addRasterLayer("/path/to/raster/file.tif", "layer name you like")
```

and i take that error message if i want to add .tif raster(other raster i can add with this method):

```
Cannot open GDAL dataset 
`/path/to/raster/file.tif': does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

and finaly i test this code from this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131160/load-the-raster-image-which-is-in-tif-format-using-qgis-api)

```
import osgeo.gdal
from  gdalconst import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo,QSettings
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

file = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 
    "Open TIF Image", ".", "Tagged image (*.tif)")
fileInfo = QFileInfo(file)    
fileName=fileInfo.fileName()
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()

layer = QgsRasterLayer(file, baseName)
```

error :

```
no module name  gdalconst
```

**that is the bug or QGIS or i do something wrong ?**

Comment: I'm quite sure there is some problem with your filepath: is there any blank space or special character in it? I tested your first code and it works for me.

Comment: In your last code snippet there is no need to import gdalconst. Comment out this line and try again. Unusual characters in file path may be a reason. Sometimes tif files have the extension tiff

Comment: i have test with the different images and paths wit all extension but no change..@mgri who is your QGIS version ?

Comment: and the last code addition error is NameError: name` 'QFileDialog' is not defined`

Comment: @ChrisPapas - You could use `from PyQt4.QtGui import QFileDialog` which should remove the name error.